# Can my remote controlled fan/light also be controlled with existing wall switches?

Tags: ceiling-fan

My old fan had a light kit also. The wiring coming from the ceiling was:

- White wire going to white wire in fan.
- Bare copper to green wire in fan.
- Red wire in ceiling to black wire in fan.
- Black wire in ceiling to blue wire for light kit on fan.

The new ceiling fan had no blue wire to connect to the black wire in ceiling for the light kit because it is remote controlled. I capped the black wire in the ceiling.

The old fan and light kit was turned on and off from two different switches on opposite walls. I now have two switches that don't control the fan and lights now.

My question is: Is there a way I can have those switches still control the fan and light, and be able to use the remote control also?

Comment: Does your remote control have a dimming function?

Comment: @Tyson -- if he doesn't mind not having dimming and/or fan speed control -- he can have it so the remote works multi-way with the wall switches, at least in some cases.

Comment: Are the existing fan switches 3 way switches?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel if that's the case it's something I don't know about, I deleted the comment.

Comment: @Tyson -- relays are quite handy parts.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the HB fans have a single power wire, so only 1 switch will work. I had the same issue after installing some, and in the one place where it really bothered us we installed one of these [https://www.amazon.com/Harbor-Breeze-Universal-Ceiling-Receiver/dp/B004FY8MR0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004FY8MR0) (essentially adding a second remote). In some other cases, we just replaced the dead switches with other things like USB charging ports or night lights.